# I'm trying to implement a popup calender when click on edittext that in a Tab Activity

Tags: android, tabs, calendar, android-edittext, popup

I'm trying to implement a popup calender when click on edittext that in a Tab Activity.My Tab activity as below. I need the code to post before the return V. Here the tab activity

```
  package com.artificers.subin.inspection;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Subin on 13-10-2015.
 */
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {


    EditText fromdate;
    EditText todate;

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_view, container, false);


        EditText fromdate=(EditText)V.findViewById(R.id.fromdate);
        EditText todate=(EditText)V.findViewById(R.id.todate);

        fromdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};

        lv = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.list_view);


        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        return V;
    }


}
```

I'm trying to implement a popup calender when click on edittext that in a Tab Activity.My Tab activity as below. I need the code to post before the return V. Here the tab activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
         final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
         public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                                  int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                if (isOkayClicked) {
                    year = selectedYear;
                    month = selectedMonth;
                    day = selectedDay;
                }
                isOkayClicked = false;
            }
        };

        final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                HomePageActivity.this, R.style.DialogTheme, datePickerListener,
                year, month, day); //use your activity name here instead of HomePageActivity

        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime()); // setting the max date

        datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                        if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            isOkayClicked = false;
                        }
                    }
                });

        datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
                "Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                        if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {

                            isOkayClicked = true;
                            DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog
                                    .getDatePicker();
                            datePickerListener.onDateSet(datePicker,
                                    datePicker.getYear(),
                                    datePicker.getMonth(),
                                    datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                        }
                    }
                });
        datePickerDialog.setCancelable(false);
        datePickerDialog.show();
```

if needed, remove final keyword..

add this to values/styles.xml

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#e9671c</item> // you can change the color here 
</style>
```

Comment: What is isOkayClicked means?

Comment: isOkayClicked (boolean) is a flag variable to check either user change the date or not..

Comment: did you declare it as a variable like "boolean isOkayClicked" in the class ??

Comment: just add "boolean isOkayClicked;"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94286/discussion-between-abidsplanet-and-subin-babu).

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

place this in your on click event

DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();

newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

also add below Fragment in your Project

class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment

```
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// Use the current date as the default date in the picker

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

}
```

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

```
}

}
```

Comment: I'm new to android How to do that?

Comment: DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();

        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");      In these lines  DatePickerFragment()  and getSupportFragmentManager(), shows error

Comment: class activity extents fragmentActivty{ class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment

implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {  }} check you write like this formate